# Split a string to multiple strings in powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

I have strings like

```
$value = "1;#Mohapatra,Mrutyunjaya (ADM) 10;#Sumit Upadhyay(ADM) 11;#Naidu,Ishan(ADM)"
```

I want to retrieve

```
"Mohapatra,Mrutyunjaya (ADM)", "Sumit Upadhyay(ADM)", "Naidu,Ishan(ADM)"
```

from `$value`.

I have tried `$value.Split(";#")[0]`. It is returning the first parameter only. But I want all the parameters

Comment: Is there something you have tried we can help you fix? It is expected that you have tried something first that we can help you fix.

Comment: I had used $value.Split(";#")[0]. It is returning the first parameter only. But I want all the parameters

Comment: try ***$value.split('#').replace(';', '')***

Comment: How are you obtaining the string of user values? Since you tagged the question with SharePoint-2010, I'm guessing these strings that you're trying to parse are values from a person or group field. In Powershell, you can access the values of a multi-select person or group field directly, using the format of `$item["Field"][i].LookupValue` or `$item["Field"][i].User.DisplayName` where `i` is an index greater than or equal to 0 and less than `$item["Field"].Count`, `$item` is a list item, and `Field` is the internal name of the column you're accessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just FYI, if you want to declare each as a variable you can say `$a,$b,$c,$d = $Value -Split (";#")` and each of `$a`, `$b`, `$c` and `$d` will retain those values.

Answer (score 3):

Split your string at sequences of `\s*\d+;#` (optional whitespace, followed by a number, a semicolon, and a hash character), and remove empty elements from the resulting list:

```
$value -split '\s*\d+;#' | Where-Object { $_ }
```